# How to convert Hex string to text data in C++

Tags: c++

I have a variable which is giving data in hex strings as follows: 68 73 2d 3c 40 40 9d 46 3c....
I want to convert this data to text format.

I have a some code. this code is giving false and unreadable data.

```
int hex_value(char hex_digit)
{
    switch (hex_digit) {
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        return hex_digit - '0';

    case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
        return hex_digit - 'A' + 10;

    case 'a': case 'b': case 'c': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
        return hex_digit - 'a' + 10;
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid hex digit");
}

std::string hex_to_string(const std::string& input)
{
    const auto len = input.length();
    if (len & 1) throw std::invalid_argument("odd length");

    std::string output;
    output.reserve(len / 2);
    for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); )
    {
        int hi = hex_value(*it++);
        int lo = hex_value(*it++);
        output.push_back(hi << 4 | lo);
    }
    return output;
}
```

When ever I run this code my program crashes. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to see where it happens, and what the values of all involved variables are at that point?

Comment: Output is of type ````std::string````. You are pushing back an ````int````. That will not work. I even do not understand the question. If you input your ````std::string```` "68 73 2d 3c 40 40 9d 46 3", what is your expected output. The ````std::string```` is already a text. Please clarify.

Comment: The solution from @ Ali is working fine for me.My actual function will be like  string EventListner::hex_to_strin(const std::string& input)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in this case the stl class stringstream may be useful:

```
std::string hex_to_string(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string output;
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    iss.setf(std::istringstream::hex, std::istringstream::basefield);

    while (!iss.eof()) {

        unsigned int n;
        iss >> n;

        if (iss.fail() || iss.bad())
            break;

        output += static_cast<char>(n);

    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: This answer is flat wrong. Please delete it. You should not post untested code. Additionally: Never use  ````while (!iss.eof()) ````. And what do you expect that the static_cast will do?

Comment: Why should not use ```while (!iss.eof()) ``` ?

Comment: There are 1000s of statements here on SO. Please read them carefully

Comment: I think it is safe to use ```while (!iss.eof())``` when i am checking operation with ```if (iss.bad() || iss.fail())```.

Comment: Yes, your `iss.fail() || iss.bad()` is saving it a bit - but _why_ not simply do `while(iss >> n) {` and skip the testing inside the loop?

Comment: because newbie readers understand more details when i separate parts of validation

Comment: The unfortunate thing about that is that they mostly pick up on the `while (!iss.eof())` part. 
There's a nice [state matrix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) @ cppreference and I made this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Zc6XAX) to make it easy to follow when the states toggle..

Answer (score 0):

You may use [std::stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) function with int base = 16 to convert string to int:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    std::cout << "Value=" << std::stoi("ff", nullptr, 16) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value=" << std::stoi("0A", nullptr, 16) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value=" << std::stoi("ffff", nullptr, 16) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output
Value=255
Value=10
Value=65535
```

For your example:

```
std::string convert(const std::string& Input) {
    if (Input.empty() || Input.size() % 2 != 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid argument");
    }

    std::string result, piece;

    for (auto it = Input.begin(); it != Input.end(); it += 2) {
        piece = std::string(&(*it), 2);
        result += std::stoi(piece, nullptr, 16);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::cout << convert("48656c6c6f20776f726c64") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
Output
Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int x;   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << "fffefffe";
    ss >> x;
    // output it as a signed type
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
}
```

the simplest answer for newer code would probably look like this: (from C++11)

```
std::string s = "0xfffefffe";
unsigned int x = std::stoul(s, nullptr, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this function is only for two charcter separted hex string ,like your input 
// hex string input charcter should be in lower case 
std::string HexToText( std::string & input )
{  int temp[2]; std::string r_str;
   for(int i=0;i<input.size();i+=3)
     {  temp[0]=0; temp[1]=0;
     
       if(isdigit(input[i]))  //if input character is digit then minus 48 to convert into int
          temp[0]= 16*(int)(input[i]-48);
       else
          temp[0]=16*(int)(input[i]-87);
          /* if input character is not digit then it would be from [a-e]
             'a' ascii is 97 and it's decimal is 10 .
             so 97-x = 10 
                 >> x=87
          */
                 
      // same for byte[1]
       if(isdigit(input[i+1]))  
           temp[1]= (int)(input[i+1]-48);
        else
           temp[1]=(int)(input[i+1]-87);
           
       // add and push
       r_str.push_back((char)(temp[0]+temp[1]));
     } 
   return r_str;
}
```

---

**Happy coding !**